# Apex installation error

Tags: database, oracle-linux

We have an Oracle environment, with the Oracle 11.2.0.4, in Oracle Linux 5 and we are trying to install Apex 5.1.1, but we always get the error below. We tried to install up to Windows Server 2012, without success:

```
> @apex_epg_config.sql  C:\app\administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_4\Apex

Procedimento PL/SQL concluido com sucesso.
Procedimento PL/SQL concluido com sucesso.
Procedimento PL/SQL concluido com sucesso.
Procedimento PL/SQL concluido com sucesso.

. Loading images directory: C:\app\administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_4\Apex/ap
ex/images

Diretório criado.

declare
*
ERRO na linha 1:
ORA-22288: falha no arquivo ou na operação LOBFILEOPEN
O sistema n+conseguiu localizar o caminho especificado.
ORA-06512: em "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 296
ORA-06512: em line 16
```

This error occurs specifically after executing the script `@apex_epg_config.sql` as sys. Any suggestions?

Comment: Diego - Read over this thread and some of the comments. It appears you simply need to NOT use the `C:\app\administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_4\Apex` path after the SQL script at the beginning and it should work. Not sure if it's a script bug or just the way Oracle and Linux work but based on some reading from the Internet on the error you see (the English version) this seems to be a problem many face and using a directory right off the root such as `/tmp`, etc. where you unzipped the package perhaps, and that resolve your problem... I'm not a Linux guy nor an Oracle guy; just some reading.

Answer (score 0):

if you read your error message you will notice that the path of the file has forward slashes in it .../apex/images that are not allowed on Windows. There seems to be a bug in the Oracle installation script on Windows. I am having the same issue.

Comment: Forward slashes are perfectly OK as path separators on Windows, except when used on the command line. "Diretório criado" is "Directory created".

Comment: It's not a problem with the forward slashes but with the directory where it expects to find the images. If you don't have your files unzipped in a directory called "apex" it fails when looking for images.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issues and fixed it by moving the apex code to c:\temp\apex1106

And then re-running. The issue seems to be caused by either a long directory path or characters like . and ' ' in the path - changing to a shorter path worked

@apex_epg_config.sql C:\Temp\apex1106

I can confirm the direction of the \ or / had no impact.

Here's part of the script output:

. Loading images directory: C:\Temp\apex1106/apex/images

Directory created.

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Comment: Seriously? Dots in the pathname cause a problem?